# Drupal services/cors api not accepting CSRF token

Tags: ajax, rest, drupal, polymer, session-cookies

I am using polymer to send ajax requests to my Drupal services api.

I send a POST to login and then a POST to create a node. When I login I am given a token which I store and pass to the next request. 
I am monitoring the the requests and responses with Charles, the token is being sent, the cookie is being set and passed on the 2nd POST but I get an "Unauthorized : CSRF validation failed" response.

When I send the request with Postman It works like a dream but for some reason it doesn't validate when sent with my app.

I have checked the token being set matches the one being sent and the only difference I've noticed is that when it's being sent again there is a prefix of ga_; something to do with google analytics? 
The expiry of the token is a month away the token matches what is returned at login and is being sent correctly. The header accepts X-CSRF-Token in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

My CORS module code is: 
`api/*|<mirror>|GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS|Authorization, Origin, Content-Type, X-CSRF-Token|true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any body has a similar issue, mine was caused by a couple of things, running Drupal and my app in the same browser causing all kinds or cookie conflicts and when passing parameters to my function that computes my request, if there were any parameters that were not used it breaks.

Hope this helps someone.